# How to execute multiple SQL files in one transaction in Azure?

Tags: c#, sql-server, powershell, azure-devops

**How do we execute multiple sql files in one transaction?**

I'm automating the CICD process with azure devops, and our asp.net core app is backed by a database.

For every change that we make to the database, we create a .sql file:

[image]

**How do we use azure devops to execute a bunch of sql files in one transaction?**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12488490/invoke-sqlcmd-for-multiple-files-in-single-transaction-using-powershell

Answer (score 1):

Concatenate them into one big file that looks like:

```
begin transaction

go

<concatenated SQL Files>

go

commit transaction
```

and run that with [Invoke-SqlCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps) with the `-AbortOnError` option.  Or use .NET SqlClient, and read the SQL Files one-by-one breaking each one into individual batches and run them all in a SqlTransaction.